# How can I fake an extension method? (System.Collections.Generic.CollectionExtensions.GetValueOrDefault)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, specflow, microsoft-fakes

[image: Functions I want to fake]

As shown in the image, I want to fake extension method (seen in Specflow's ScenarioContext class) : `public bool TryGetValue<TValue>(string key, out TValue value)`

I've created fakes for the System.Collection assembly (which contains the IDictionary extension method), but I do not understand how to fake a function which has parameters. I do know how to fake for a parameterless function such as the File.IO.ReadAllLines() function :

```
            using (ShimsContext.Create())
            {
            System.IO.ShimFile.ReadAllLines = m => new string[]{};
            ....
```

Can I get help understanding how to mock this extension method:
System.Collections.Generic.CollectionExtensions.GetValueOrDefault

... I honestly tried looking for examples, but the only ones I could find were parameterless functions or getters.

Comment: What do you mean by "fake", exactly?

Comment: That isn't an extension method

Comment: Tests should be mocking the dependencies of the class/method being tested, more especially when these dependencies traverse application boundaries (file I/O, network, database access, etc.). If your tested method needs a collection or a dictionary, a test should be able to just supply one, perhaps with bogus content: there is usually no need to fake or mock them. Mocking TryGetValue could actually be somewhat dangerous: you could end up with a green test with a flawed setup, and the method actually blows up during normal execution because it doesn't behave exactly like your mock.

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Copy and paste it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you are talking about [Microsoft Fakes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/isolating-code-under-test-with-microsoft-fakes?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp).

To provide a fake implementation of a method with parameters the documentation specifies the following:

> Name is original name + parameter types:

So for ReadAllLines I would expect the name to be `ReadAllLinesString`. Your editor should be able to show you what delegates are available to assign to.

But this is not an extension method, just a regular static method. You would typically not mock extension methods, since these are just providing extra functionality. Mock the underlying type instead.

In the case of CollectionExtensions.GetValueOrDefault I would argue that you should mock the underlying `Dictionary.TryGetValue` that I assume GetValueOrDefault uses. I would however argue that faking or mocking collections is not very useful. Mocking tend to be most useful when used on the "edges" of some module, like replacing file system functions as an example. Collections are a fairly integral part of .Net, so there is much less to be gained  by trying to mock them, IMHO.

Comment: I updated my question for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a distinction that may be of use to you: Given a choice of extensions, the compiler will choose the more-constrained version. So for example if you want`GetValueOrDefault()` to return a mocked result for a `SpecFlowContext` then make an extension for `this SpecFlowContext`.

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static object GetValueOrDefault<TKey>(
        this SpecFlowContext dictionary, 
        TKey key) where TKey : notnull
    {
        return "Fake value A";
    }

    public static object GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(
        this SpecFlowContext dictionary, 
        TKey key, 
        [AllowNull] TValue defaultValue)
    {
        if(defaultValue is string valid)
        {
            return valid;
        }
        return "Fake value B";
    }
}
```

---

**TEST**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Normal dictionary
        var normal = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "Apple", "Red" },
            { "Orange", "Orange" },
        };
        Console.WriteLine(normal.GetValueOrDefault("Apple"));


        // SpecFlowContext dictionary
        var fake = new CustomSpecFlowContext
        {
            { "Apple", "Red" },
            { "Orange", "Orange" },
        };
        Console.WriteLine(fake.GetValueOrDefault("Apple"));
        Console.WriteLine(fake.GetValueOrDefault("Apple", (string)null));
        Console.WriteLine(fake.GetValueOrDefault("Apple", "Fake value C"));
    }
}
// Class that implements abstract SpecFlowCOntext
class CustomSpecFlowContext : SpecFlowContext { }
```

[image: console output]

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/specflow-mock.git) this example.

Comment: I'm honestly surprised by the level of detail in the post - I learnt a lot, thank you.

I failed to mention this in the original post:

Comment: I'm trying this out, will report back once I do so..